# Using Parallel process to update object attributes in main process

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I've been looking into the multiprocessing module to figure this out but I'm not entirely sure of all the components I need or how to structure them.  The basic structure/logic that I'm trying to get goes something like this though:

```
import datetime
import time
import multiprocessing

class So_Classy():
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 0

    def update_values(self):
        print('In the process doing stuff!')
        while True:
            self.value = self.value + 1
            time.sleep(0.1)
            print("Self.value = {self.value}")

    def run(self):
        # Constantly update old value to a new one
        try:
            if __name__ == '__main__':
                p = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.update_values)
                p.start()
                print("Process started!")
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))

    def get_result(self, arg):
        return self.value*arg

##### MAIN PROGRAM #####
# Initialize process given certain parameters
sc = So_Classy()

# This spawns a process running an infinite while loop
sc.run()

one_second = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=1)

while True:
    if datetime.datetime.now() > one_second:
        # Pass an arg to sc and do a calc with it
        print(sc.get_result(5))
        one_second = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=1)
```

The run() function is making it through to the end without causing an exception but it doesn't appear to actually be entering the process.  No idea why. :\

The real process I will be using will be computationally intensive so it has to run as a separate process.